# ios notification, define handler function directly

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I want to do some actions when receiving "ready" notification.

Basically, we do :

```
// earlier in a method
    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector( notificationHandler )
     name:@"ready"
     object:nil];


// later in file
- (X) notificationHandler{
    ...
}
```

In my case, the method which will handle the notification will be an one-line standing function, so if possible, I would like to define it right in the observer block.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector( I WANT TO DEFINE A FUNCTION HERE )
 name:@"ready"
 object:nil];
```

Any idea ?

Comment: which way are you talking about ?

Comment: Sorry..  This is what I wanted to say:     it is a good practice to use - (void)notificationHandler:(id)sender and then in the selector make sure you have @selector(notificationHandler:)   Now. Going to your question.  Did you try     [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:<#(NSString *)#> object:<#(id)#> queue:<#(NSOperationQueue *)#> usingBlock:<#^(NSNotification *note)block#>]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there are some official APIs to do this, I strongly suggest you to **NOT** use them, cause they're [leaked](http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsnotificationcenter-with-blocks-considered-harmful/). You can use [FXNotifications](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXNotifications) from Nick Lockwood, which provides the feature you want: use a block as notification listener.

Add the `.h` & `.m` files inside your project and then call:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          forName:@"ready"
                                           object:nil
                                            queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                       usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note, id observer) {
                                                       // Your inline function here
                                                  }];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to let you know that exist this method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"ready" 
                                                  object:nil 
                                                   queue:nil 
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    //Do something
}];
```

and also that you are talking about write a **function** or a **block** in a `@selector` directive...doesn't make sense and is not possible.

Enjoy the function above ;)

Comment: That is what I'm looking for. Nice

Comment: Please, do not use this solution. This method is bugged and has some serious leaks. It's prone to errors. Refer to http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsnotificationcenter-with-blocks-considered-harmful/ for more details.